# Neo4j 3.0.0-M02 changes the data if property size is >10Kb

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm trying out Neo4j version 3.0.0-M02 using the neo4j-java-driver driver version 1.0.0-M02.

1. I'm creating a node with a property with ~10Kb of data.
2. When I retrieve the node the data has changed, but not the length.

If I create the node with smaller amount of data (~1Kb) it works as it should.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

**EDIT:**
The driver I'm using is in Alpha so I'm guessing that's the problem.

```
    //byte[] b = new byte[1000]; //works
    byte[] b = new byte[7000]; //does not work

    new Random().nextBytes(b);

    sun.misc.BASE64Encoder encoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
    String data = encoder.encode(b);

    Session session = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost").session();

    String createQuery = "CREATE (a:Asset {" +
            "id : {id}," +
            "type : 'test'," +
            "created : {created}," +
            "data: {data}" +
            "}) RETURN a";

    String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    long created = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Map<String,Value> createValues = Values.parameters("id",id,"created",created,"data",data);

    session.run(createQuery,createValues);

    String matchQuery = "MATCH (a:Asset {id : {id}}) RETURN a.data as data";
    Map<String,Value> matchValues = Values.parameters("id",id);

    ResultCursor matchCursor = session.run(matchQuery,matchValues);

    matchCursor.list().get(0).asMap().forEach((k,v) -> {
        Assert.assertEquals(data.length(),v.asString().length());
        Assert.assertEquals(data,v.asString());
    });
    session.close();
```

Comment: Please raise it as a GitHub issue on: http://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver

Comment: I added a issue at Github: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver/issues/119

Answer (score 0):

The version I tested was the Maven one.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-M02</version>
    </dependency>
```

The version in the repo https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver.git works as expected.